# Unresponsive redis:works fine after FLUSHALL

Tags: redis

We observered a sporadic issue (once in every month or 2) in our redis. Suddenly we see that redis read/write calls from our application returns a failure. At that point we are still able to connect to redis from redis-cli and doing a FLUSHALL resolves the issue.

Has anyone encountered this kind of issue. Our redis version is 4.0.9. Since we are not observing any issue in connecting to redis, we are not suspecting issue with Jedis Client.

Comment: Did you try anything such as `client list`, `info memory`,  `redis-cli --bigkeys` or any spike on the monitoring tools if you are using(aws elasticache) ?

Comment: No...our operation team did not take any statistics at that point of time, we have asked them to do next time onwards.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of redis calls? Something that writes the data or reads the data?

All in all, just as an idea, examine your redis.conf file
It has Maxmemory configuration directive, and when redis reaches max memory limit it acts according to eviction policy.

If the policy is set to 'noeviction', the behavior sounds like what you've described (from their documentation):

> return errors when the memory limit was reached and the client is trying to execute commands that could result in more memory to be used (most write commands, but DEL and a few more exceptions).

You can configure redis as a cache so that it will delete some entries by itself.

Read about this [here](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache)

Comment: "What kind of redis calls? Something that writes the data or reads the data?" - Yes